# angular with c# web api cross domain doesnt work

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to populate an angular with a result from json request on a web api without succcess.

without success. I want to make a angular application which read from my web api a result.
All i got is a error GET http://jobshop-webapi.validando.com.br/api/login?callback=jsonp_callback 404 (Not Found)

Its a cross-domain ajax request but i've tried everything i found.

http://jobshop-webapi.validando.com.br/api/login?email=login@email.com&password=senha
Including the header. I really dont know the reason.

Please, someone give some light.

**EDIT**

Response header is here:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Length:49
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 02 May 2013 14:47:45 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET

**EDIT**

http://jsbin.com/egonid/12/edit

here is my code :( doesnt works yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response needs to add a header:

http://patelshailesh.com/index.php/cross-domain-asp-net-web-api-call-using-ajax

This one works! :)